# Want to create a list inside a list using a string

Tags: string, list, matrix

I want to create a multiple list of lists using a string. 
For example, when I am given a string like 1,2;3,4| 5,6;7,8|9,0;7,6|4,3;2,1
; will divide the string so that it goes to the next row of the string 
and | will start a new matrix
so the string in the example will create [[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]], [[9,0],[7,6]], [[4,3], [2,1]].

I tried to split the string by ; and |, but don't know what to do from there

```
CS = content.split('|')
LIST = [i.split(';') for i in CS]
```

Please help me out. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you can use numpy, then numpy.matrix can be initialized from string:

```py
import numpy as np

content = '1,2;3,4|5,6;7,8|9,0;7,6|4,3;2,1'
cs = content.split('|')
list = [np.matrix(i).tolist() for i in cs]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to  use bumpy yet.  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
content = '1,2;3,4|5,6;7,8|9,0;7,6|4,3;2,1'

CS = content.split('|')
LIST = [i.split(';') for i in CS]

# double list comprehension to group the integers into lists
lis = [[i] for j in LIST for i in j]

# group the result lists by evenly-sized chunks    
lis = [lis[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(lis), 2)]

print lis

# Output:
#  [
#      [
#          ['1,2'], ['3,4']
#      ], 
#      [
#          ['5,6'], ['7,8']
#      ], 
#      [   
#          ['9,0'], ['7,6']
#      ], 
#      [
#          ['4,3'], ['2,1']
#      ]
#  ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert the strings to floats?

Comment: NVM I figured out another way